# Android dialog with edittext() keeps coming back null throw exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to create a simple dialog box to allow my user to create a new user. I have the layout the way i need it but for some reason when i click the Create button it throws an exception. I have tried various way to accomplish this but i must be leaving something out. I am now on day two of this error and I am all out of options. I have ever re-wrote the code twice and went over with a fine tooth comb.

here is what i have so far:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    //new user button, work in progress
    Button newuser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_user);
    newuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog createU = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);



            createU.setContentView(R.layout.newuser);
            createU.setTitle("Create User");

            Button create = (Button) createU.findViewById(R.id.createUsr);
            Button cancel = (Button) createU.findViewById(R.id.cancel);



            create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//creates the user

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String usr = null, pass = null;
                    EditText userU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.createUsr);
                    EditText passU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

                    if(userU.getText()!= null){//throws ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9937): java.lang.NullPointerException

                        usr = userU.getText().toString();
                    }
                    if(passU.getText()!=null){
                        pass = passU.getText().toString();
                    }


                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User: " + usr + ", Pass: " + pass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//closes dialog

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    createU.hide();
                }
            });
            createU.show();
        }
    });
   }
 }
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/usrTxt" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:maxLines="1" android:hint="Username"
    android:text="2"></EditText>
<EditText android:id="@+id/pasTxt" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_below="@id/usrTxt"
    android:inputType="textPassword" android:maxLines="1" android:hint="Password"
    android:text="2"></EditText>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pasTxt" android:text="Create" android:id="@+id/createUsr"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="Cencel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pasTxt"></Button>
```

Comment: Could you also post the xml for the newuser layout? Also, what exception does it throw, and from what line?

Comment: Can you show the full error trace

Comment: I have narrowed it down to when i call the .gettext(), every way i put it it just throw a ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9937): java.lang.NullPointerException 

let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not initialize strings with null values

avoid `String usr = null, pass = null;` . Hope that will help.

**Update:**

Change the above line causing error as

```
if (!userU.getText().toString().equals("")) {
```

**Update2**

Change the Edittext initialization lines as below

```
  EditText userU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usrTxt);                     
  EditText passU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pasTxt);
```

Comment: i will make note of that, i believe i was just testing something when i create that line.

Comment: Tried that. That was my first line of code. Every time I call .gettext() or anything it throws null. Review my edited code.

Comment: You are passing wrong Id. You are passing id for buttons to Edittext.

Comment: I guess i didn't see that at first. I also updated the code to reflect the dialog itself. all is well. thanks everyone for your help. back to work i go, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is these lines in `onClick(View v)`:

```
EditText userU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.createUsr);
EditText passU = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
```

It is searching your main layout for those views and it is not finding them. Try changing them to:

```
EditText userU = (EditText) createU.findViewById(R.id.createUsr);
EditText passU = (EditText) createU.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
```

and the NullPointerException should go away.

But this code is a little odd. The onClickListener is already attached to the R.id.createUsr button, so that's what's being passed as the View to onClick. There's no reason to find it again. Also, it's a button, not an EditText; are you sure this is the view you want to be testing?

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, but I guess i dont follow you on the whole button thing. 

also as Tusher pointed out i was referencing the wrong id for edittext. if you could explain the button thing again. I did manage to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to wrong resource.

```
findViewById(R.id.usrTxt);               
findViewById(R.id.pasTxt);
```

resource from .xml file.

You should refer to the dialog resource.

```
dialog.findViewById(R.id.usrTxt);               
dialog.findViewById(R.id.pasTxt);
```